# How to create a data frame from a deeply nested dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas

I have a nested dictionary that has 5 levels `masterdict = {a : {b: {c: {d : { e:  }}}}}` and I am trying to create a flat data frame.

When I run the following code:

```
masterDF = pd.DataFrame()

for a in masterdict:
   for b in masterdict[a]:
      for c in masterdict[a][b]:
         for d in masterdict[a][b][c]:
            eDF = pd.DataFrame(masterdict[a][b][c][d])
            eDF['level4'] = str(d)
            eDF['level3'] = str(c)
            eDF['level2'] = str(b)
            eDF['level1'] = str(a)
            masterDF = masterDF.append(eDF)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PandasError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-cc9930935c64> in <module>()
      5       for c in masterdict[a][b]:
      6          for d in masterdict[a][b][c]:
----> 7             eDF = pd.DataFrame(masterdict[a][b][c][d])
      8             eDF['level4'] = str(d)
      9             eDF['level3'] = str(c)

C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.pyc in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    275                                          copy=False)
    276             else:
--> 277                 raise PandasError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
    278 
    279         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I am not sure if this is the right code to flatten a nested dictionary but if it is, could you please suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide us with a mock object? Im suspecting this is a json file ?

Answer (score 0):

I write this to flatten nested dictionaries. Might help you also. pk becomes a string of previous key, and current key with a ' to join them. a becomes a list of items.

```
a=[]
heading=[]
def flat_dict(dic,pk=None):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            try:
                flat_dict(v,pk+"'"+k)
            except:
                flat_dict(v,k)
        else:
            a.append(v)
        try: 
            heading.append(pk+"'"+k)
            # print pk+'\''+k,v
        except:
            heading.append(k)
            # print k,v
```